# Should there be a limit on how often a user is allowed to view rewarded ads?

Tags: ios, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad, firebase-admob

I have an app that allows the user to spin a wheel to earn tickets. I allow users to watch a rewarded ad to retry the spin, this means the user can view as many ads as they want.

Is there any policy on how often a user should be allowed to view a rewarded ad? I can't find any information on this?

Answer (score 2):

**Rewarded Interstitial Format specific policies**

In addition to the common rewarded inventory policies, Rewarded Interstitial ads must also adhere to the following format specific policies ( reference https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7313578
):

**Follow the Interstitial ad guidance for both Disallowed and Recommended interstitial implementation**

Disallowed Interstitial implementation link - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362

So there is no direct cap on number of times rewarded video should be displayed but **You should place no more than one interstitial ad after every two user actions within your app. Please note that this requirement also applies when a user clicks the Back button within the app.**